# How can i use signals in django bulk create

Tags: python, django, signals

I have this code

`Task.objects.bulk_create(ces)`

Now this is my signal

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Task)
def save_hours(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    logger.debug('test')
```

Now this signal is not triggered in bulk create

I am using django 1.8

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As mentioned `bulk_create` does not trigger these signals -

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

> This method inserts the provided list of objects into the database in
>   an efficient manner (generally only 1 query, no matter how many
>   objects there are).
>
> This has a number of caveats though:
>
> - The model’s save() method will not be called, and the pre_save and post_save signals will not be sent.
> - It does not work with child models in a multi-table inheritance scenario.
> - If the model’s primary key is an AutoField it does not retrieve and set the primary key attribute, as save() does.
> - It does not work with many-to-many relationships.
> - The batch_size parameter controls how many objects are created in single query. The default is to create all objects in one batch,
>     except for SQLite where the default is such that at most 999 variables
>     per query are used.

So you have to trigger them manually. If you want this for all models you can override the `bulk_create` and send them yourself like this -

```
class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def bulk_create(items,....):
         super().bulk_create(...)
         for i in items:
              [......] # code to send signal
```

Then use this manager -

```
class Task(models.Model):
    objects = CustomManager()
    ....
```

Answer (score 12):

Iterating on the answer above:

Python 2:

```
class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def bulk_create(self, objs, **kwargs):
        #Your code here
        return super(models.Manager,self).bulk_create(objs,**kwargs)
```

Python 3:

```
class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def bulk_create(self, objs, **kwargs):
        #Your code here
        return super(CustomManager, self).bulk_create(objs,**kwargs)
```

---

```
class Task(models.Model):
    objects = CustomManager()
    ....
```

Complete answer in python 2:

```
class CustomManager(models.Manager):

def bulk_create(self, objs, **kwargs):
    a = super(models.Manager,self).bulk_create(objs,**kwargs)
    for i in objs:
        post_save.send(i.__class__, instance=i, created=True)
    return a
```

Comment: Problem is if you would use 'ignore_conflicts=True' then you newer know how much instances are created in fact. It might be 15 of 20 for example, or 19, or 20 or None

Comment: `objs` might be an iterator, so a more robust code would first convert it into a list, then call super().bulk_create(...) and then iterate over the items in order to send the signals.