# One place to monitor modifications of django model

Tags: python, django

I have model:

```
class UserAvailableCredit(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        "auth_ex.User",
        related_name="credits",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    payment = models.ForeignKey(
        Payment,
        related_name="credits",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project,
        related_name="credits",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

and on this model I make various actions like:

1. Bulk creating
2. Deleting
3. Updating
   etc.

is there any way to have one method that on any change of model triggers action?

1. Overwriting save method doesn't solve problem when bulk_create action is triggered.

In my solution I have done something like this:

```
class UserAvailableCreditQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def update(self, **kwargs):
        notify = kwargs.pop("notify", False)
        if notify:
          #custom action

    def bulk_create(self, objs, batch_size=None):
        super().bulk_create(objs, batch_size)
        #custom action


class UserAvailableCredit(models.Model):
    """Model to store available users credits to use with plan limitations."""

    objects = UserAvailableCreditQuerySet.as_manager()
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        "auth_ex.User",
        related_name="credits",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    payment = models.ForeignKey(
        Payment,
        related_name="credits",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project,
        related_name="credits",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["id"]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        #custom action

    def create(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().create(*args, **kwargs)
        #custom action

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
        #custom action
```

But I am not sure if it is best way to solve this problem.

Comment: Look into Django signals

Comment: Ok, but what signal can trigger this action?

Comment: There are different signals for save, delete. etc The code inside it will be triggered automatically when it happens(When you create update or delete). check it out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/

Comment: Yes, but there are for example post_save signals - but they do not trigger when for example bulk_create method is executed.

Comment: yes, signals won't be triggered for bulk_create. But you can create your own signals and trigger them. Check out this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30632743/how-can-i-use-signals-in-django-bulk-create