# what's the most efficient way to check for orphans when deleting objects in Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, database

Say I have a model with a `Things` table and a table of relationships between the things called `ThingRelations`. It should not be possible to delete a `Thing` when there are `ThingRelations` that point to it, and when there are no more `ThingRelations` pointing to a given `Thing`, it should be deleted. I'm currently trying to implement that with `signals.post_delete` like this:

```py
from django.db import models

class ThingRelation(models.Model):
    first_thing = models.ForeignKey('Thing', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    second_thing = models.ForeignKey('Thing', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Thing(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=260)

@receiver(models.signals.post_delete, sender=ThingRelation)
def check_relation_and_delete(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    for thing_id in [instance.first_thing, instance.second_thing]:
        first_thing_match = ThingRelation.objects.filter(first_thing=thing_id).exists()
        second_thing_match = ThingRelation.objects.filter(second_thing=thing_id).exists()
        if not first_thing_match and not second_thing_match:
            Thing.objects.get(pk=thing_id).delete()
```

Is this the most efficient way to find and delete orphaned `Things`? I'm very new to databases in general, but won't filtering the (potentially quite large) `Things` table four times for every deleted `ThingRelation` be slow when deleting many objects at once? Is there some kind of SQL or Django functionality that makes it so this code isn't run for every object in a bulk operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`signals.py` [is not designed for bulk operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30632743/how-can-i-use-signals-in-django-bulk-create). Also they are often considered an [anti-pattern](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/), because of difficulty of traceability them when you trying to debug some logic.

I'd rather advise you to try routine approach here. An example, which might be helpful for you:

```py
def remove_orphaned_things():
    orphaned_things = Thing.objects.filter(
        ~Q(id__in=ThingRelation.objects.values_list('first_thing_id').filter(
            first_thing_id=OuterRef('pk')
        ) | ~Q(id__in=ThingRelation.objects.values_list('second_thing_id').filter(
            second_thing_id=OuterRef('pk')
        )
    ).delete()
```

This function removes all orphaned `Thing`'s. So all that left is we need to call it properly.

The most easy and straightforward way is to organise it to endless `while-true` routine with some `sleep` and run it as a daemon. For example:

```py
from datetime import time
from django.core.management import BaseCommand
# Also some import of `remove_orphaned_things`

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        while True:
            remove_orphaned_things()
            time.sleep(300)
```

So it would be executed nearly once per 5 minutes. It could be run with something like [`supervisor`](http://supervisord.org/) (better) or [`tmux`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux) (worse), so you can be sure it's always running.

The better way is to use something like `periodic` to orchestrate it. Here is [an installation guide](https://dramatiq.io/installation.html) (you'd also need RabbitMQ) and a little example how to organise it:

```py
@dramatiq.actor(periodic=cron('*/5 * * * *'), max_retries=0)
def remove_orphaned_things():
    # Exact the same code of `remove_orphaned_things`
```

Good luck!

Comment: is it unreasonable to have a set of functions like this and just run them after any delete method is called? is a daemon preferable over that approach?

Comment: If you need to utilise `Thing`'s immediately, it's totally reasonable. But if your primary goal is performance, then you should better go with bulk approach, it's way more efficient. If you are concerned about big size of `Thing` table, it could be helpful to add a field like `relation_count` with index on it to `Thing` and maintain it (update on each change in `ThingRelations`). Thus you can find all `Thing`'s without long gathering data on `ThingRelations` with one index search.

Comment: ah, the counter is a great idea. is it possible to increment the relation count automatically when creating a `ThingRelation` or would I need to write a separate function?

Comment: Of course, you can do it with `signals.py` signals `post_save` and `post_delete` of `ThingRelations`. But it's a much clearer solution to develop a special class with database level logic. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12857584/12914274) are some some great ideas about separation of business and data logic in django.